# Converting a lambda to function pointer typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback

I have a 3rd party API that has a function that takes a function pointer as an argument (sample types):

```
// defined in "Api.h"
typedef int (*Callback) (int x); 

unsigned char ApiCall(int p, Callback cb);


int ApiCall(int p, Callback cb) {
   return cb(p);
}
```

And I'm trying interact with this API using a class instance method; here's a sample class:

```
class ApiWrapper {
    public:
        int ApiCallback(int x) { return this->factor_ * x; }

        static int WorkingApiCallback(int x) { return 3 * x; }

        ApiWrapper(int f) { this->factor_ = f; }

    private:
        int factor_;
}
```

And a main function to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    ApiWrapper a(2);

    using std::placeholders::_1;
    std::function<int(int)> lambda = std::bind( &ApiWrapper::ApiCallback, a, _1 );

    std::cout << "Class: "  << a.ApiCallback(21) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Lambda: " << lambda(21) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Static ApiCall:" << ApiCall(21, ApiWrapper::WorkingApiCallback) << std::endl;

    // NOT WORKING 
    std::cout << "Static ApiCall:" << ApiCall(21, lambda) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Static ApiCall:" << ApiCall(21, this.ApiCallback) << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using the `static` member; as I need to associate/use state each time the callback is invoked by the 3rd party lib.

- Online Runnable Source: https://ideone.com/7nVSi8

Thanks!

Comment: Pointers to non-`static` class methods are incompatible with C-like function pointers, due to the fact, that they have pass `this` pointer as their first argument. I.e. The method `ApiCallback` in `class ApiWrapper { int ApiCallback(int x); };` is represented as `int ApiCallback (ApiWrapper* this, int x);` internally. And now it's obvious why it isn't compatible with `typedef int (*Callback) (int x);`

Comment: hmm, thank you for the comment, yeah, I figured, was hoping for there to be a workaround or maybe something that I might be missing, this will force me to track state inside of the static member :(

Comment: Well.. The state needs to be stored somewhere, it either can be passed into the function (requiring an additional argument, making the signature different, and, hence, incompatible), or global (not requiring to pass it into the function - not requiring to change function signature).

Comment: The last one you can call like this `std::cout << "Static ApiCall:" << ApiCall(21, ApiWrapper{2}.ApiCallback) << std::endl;`

Comment: are you sure that the x argument of the api's callback is an int, and not a void*?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to somehow associate a non-member with the function pointer, as it does not take any sort of context argument. You are going to have a non-member function at some point, no way around that. And that function cannot be a capturing lambda.

One option is to have a (possibly thread local) global pointer that holds the instance.

i.e. you do:

```
myType * glbInst;
..void someFunc()
{
 myType myInst;
  glbInst = &myInst;
  apiCall([] (int)  glbInst->member(x); });
}
```

Another option is to use libffi's closure system to create a function at run-time and have the instance be part of the saved data. I use this pattern very often but it's a bit complicated to paste here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!, 
> I use this pattern very often but it's a bit complicated to paste here.

Perhaps a link to paste bin?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this without using the static member;

There's a hackish solution.

1. Define a non-member function.
2. Store a pointer to an object that can be accessed by the non-member function.
3. Call the member function of the object from the non-member function.

---

```
ApiWrapper* objectForCallback = NULL; 

int  NonMemberFunction(int x)
{
   assert(objectForCallback != NULL);
   return objectForCallback->ApiCallback(x);
}
```

and the setup for the above to work:

```
ApiWrapper a(2);
objectForCallback = &a;
```

Now you can use:

```
std::cout << "Static ApiCall:" << ApiCall(21, NonMemberFunction) << std::endl;
```